# Convert DbContext way to SqlCommand way

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, entity-framework, asp.net-core

Today I have an App which work using EF Core, with the DbContext class and looks like this:

```csharp
    public class RcoreContext : DbContext
    {
        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(@"Server=(localdb)\mssqllocaldb;Database=rCoreData.TestDb;Trusted_Connection=True;");
        }

        public DbSet<Hosts> Hosts { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Route> Route { get; set; }
    }

    public class Hosts
    {
        public int      HostsId  { get; set; }
        public string   Host     { get; set; }

        [NotMapped]
        public Dictionary<object, object> Datas { get; set; }

        public string   DatasJson { get { return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Datas); } set { Datas = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<object, object>>(value); } }
    }

    public class Route
    {
        public int                          RouteId     { get; set; }
        public int                          HostId      { get; set; }
        public string                       RealRoute   { get; set; }
        public string                       alias       { get; set; }
    }
```

I very like this way because the requests returns are based on existing classes (`Hosts` and `Route` in this code).

The SqlCommand way seems more comfortable to use (it seems to be more PHP-like) but seems to return the entries as `object`. (I read [this article](https://www.dotnetperls.com/sqlcommand))

I would like to know if is it possible to make a mix between the 2 ways and to send a request as a StoredProcedure like SqlCommand do BUT still be based on existing classes for the request return.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

if you want to use ADO.NET in EF, you just need to get the current connection string and create the sqlcommand as below:

```
using (var context = new RcoreContext())
{
   // creates a Command 
   var command = context.Database.Connection.CreateCommand();
   command.CommandType = commandType;
   command.CommandText = sql;

   using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
    {
        while (reader.Read())
        {
        for (int i = 0; i < reader.FieldCount; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(reader.GetValue(i));
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }
}
```

and if you just want to execute sql or stored procedure, you can also use below in EF

```
 _dbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(sql, parameters);
_dbContext.Database.SqlQuery<TEntity>(sql, parameters);
```

Comment: Hello, `_dbContext.Database.SqlQuery<TEntity>(sql, parameters);` seems to be what I look for but I use ASP.NET Core 1.0 (so EF Core) and `.SqlQuery()` does not exist. Instead of it, I can use `.FromSql()`, is it possible to use stored procedure with it ? Thanks

Comment: I think you can take a look [this](http://dotnetthoughts.net/how-to-execute-storedprocedure-in-ef-core/)

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what i want

Answer (score 2):

```
    using (var connection = context.Database.GetDbConnection())
    using (var command = context.Database.GetDbConnection().CreateCommand())
    { 
       command.CommandText = string.Format(sqlQuery, id);
       connection.Open();
       using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader()){}
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
using (var connection = new SqlConnection(_dbContext.Database.Connection.ConnectionString))
using (var cmd = new SqlCommand())
{
      cmd.Connection = connection;
      cmd.CommandText = "your query here";
      cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

      cmd.Parameters.Add("@param1", SqlDbType.Int);

      cmd.Connection.Open();
      cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```